# Convert string with timezone to date

Tags: swift, date, swift3, timezone

I have this type of string and want to convert it to date

> "2017-05-27T00:00:00.000+0400"

but none of this formatters convert it to date

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSSZ"

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSSX"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your forgot to add `ss` for seconds so correct formate should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-05-27T00:00:00.000+0400")
```

Comment: @NarekSimonyan Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 2):

Your error was that the `seconds` were missing. So the right format should be: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`. You can also use an extension for this purpose:

```
extension String {
    var toCustomDate: Date {
        return Date.Formatter.customDate.date(from: self)!
    }
}

extension Date {
    struct Formatter {
        static let customDate: DateFormatter = {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
            return formatter
        }()
    }

    var customDate: String {
        return Formatter.customDate.string(from: self)
    }
}

let str = "2017-05-27T00:00:00.000+0400"
let date = str.toCustomDate
```

If you have more date formats, then just add them to the extensions.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
let dateString = "2017-05-27T00:00:00.000+0400"
    let formachanger = DateFormatter()
    formachanger .dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    if let dateFromString = formachanger .date(from: dateString) {
        formachanger .dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        let stringFromDate = formachanger .string(from: dateFromString)
    }
```

Comment: The question is not about changing the string to a different format.

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
        func getGMTDateFrom(String string : String) -> Date? {

            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zz"
            let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: string)
            return dateObj
        }
```

Change date format according to your need.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?